# Pass readonly parameter to mutable function (which will not mutate)

Tags: typescript, readonly, type-safety, dataloader

I need to create a function `batchUsers` which takes a `readonly string` as a parameter to create a DataLoader. In my `batchUsers` function I need to call a function (`User.findby`) which has defined its parameter not as readonly.

```
type BatchUser = (ids: readonly string[]) => Promise<User[]>;

const batchUsers:BatchUser = async (ids) => {
  const users = await User.findBy({ id: In(ids) });

  // reordering the users to match the ids
  const userMap: { [key: string]: User } = {};
  users.forEach((u) => {
    userMap[u.id] = u;
  })
  return ids.map((id) => userMap[id]);
}

export const userLoader = () => new DataLoader<string, User>(batchUsers)
```

Here I get the error: `The type 'readonly string[]' is 'readonly' and cannot be assigned to the mutable type 'string[]'` on thre ids in the findBy function

Alternatively if I set

```
type BatchUser = (ids: string[]) => Promise<User[]>;
```

Then I get the error:

```
Argument of type 'BatchUser' is not assignable to parameter of type 'BatchLoadFn<string, User>'.
  Types of parameters 'ids' and 'keys' are incompatible.
    The type 'readonly string[]' is 'readonly' and cannot be assigned to the mutable type 'string[]'
```

in the last line where I create the new Dataloader

How can I avoid this?

Comment: What's the last error?

Comment: Your "last error" is just the definition of `BatchUser`. That's not an error and it's the crucial piece of information we need to answer the question. Could you update the question to include the error?

Comment: @caTS sorry copy paste error - I fixed it now

Comment: @caTS any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I don't know why `DataLoader` has made the argument a readonly array, but I think the only way is to cast it.... [Here's a minimal example](https://tsplay.dev/WzPOQN)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found to make this work leand on the suggestion of caTS and does:

```js
const users = await User.findBy({ id: In(ids as string[]) });
```

instead of

```js
const users = await User.findBy({ id: In(ids) });
```